# element by id is null when running tests (Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null)

Tags: reactjs, testing, npm, jestjs, echarts

[EDITED]: an earlier version of this question mistakenly though the `echarts` variable was `null`, when it was the result of `getElementById`. I confirmed this by remove `el` from the function call, and that part of the test did not generate a similar error, implying that `echarts` was in fact available.

---

I am using create-react-app, which uses the jest test runner, and am using echarts.

```js
import echarts from 'echarts/lib/echarts';

//...

    const el = document.getElementById('the-chart');
    this.chart = echarts.init(el);

//...

// lots of unecessary context ...'d out here:
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={...}>
        <div className={...}><!-- ... --></div>
        <div className={classes.metricsGraph} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
          <div id="the-chart" style={{width: "600px",height: "400px"}}></div>
        </div>
        <div className={...}><!-- ... --></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This works when I load the page in a browser. However, when I run tests, I get, on this last line,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

The value of `el`, returned by `document.getElementById` must be returning `null`, but only in the test environment. This code is being called in the components `componentDidMount` callback.

How can I proceed to make this test pass? Is there another way to get the element or another event I should wait for in the test environment to have this element accessible? Where can I look to discover why this is different in test vs browser?

I am relatively new to node / npm, jest, Javascript that sin't from the 90's, and React, so any pointers to things I'm not thinking about correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show the code where the "the-chart" element is being rendered? In react it's better to use refs instead of getElementById, but I'd like to see some context

Comment: Updated to add the relevant parts of the `render()` function! I'll play around with `React.createRef` to see if that can make this work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that getElementById is returning null, are you? Did you check with a quick console.log? It should be working if that's being called in componentdidmount.. Hmmm... Anyway, give refs a try, and go with `this.chart = echarts.init(this.myRef)`

Comment: console.log confirms it. With `this.chartRef = React.createRef();` in the constructor, I'm getting `{ current: null }` for `this.chartRef` in the `componentDidMount` function. So it has the structure of a ref but it's still not getting the actual DOM element. Again it's gotta have something to do with the test runner, but I'm baffled.

Comment: Are you using shallow render for this test?

Comment: I haven't specified it, and it looks like from [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#testing-components) it's not the default behavior, so I'm guessing no but am not 100% confident since I'm just using the scaffolded tests from create-react-app.

Comment: Hm, from a part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694975/jest-enzyme-using-mount-document-getelementbyid-returns-null-on-componen) I found that it might help to attach the created root element using `document.body.appendChild(div);`, where `div` is created as part of the test code. That gets me further -- the line in question succeeds but a related error happens down the line, another "can't do xyz to `null`" error. Blerg. I'll probe further into that error, but at least it's progress!

Comment: That's interesting, and definitely beyond me..