# getting 'NULL' error while I am testing 'document.getElementByID' line. I already tried attachTo approach but that is also not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I am testing my react function using jest. While I am testing I am getting error **focus of null** for document.getElementById line.

I already tried this solution.
[jest + enzyme, using mount(), document.getElementById() returns null on component which appear after _method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694975/jest-enzyme-using-mount-document-getelementbyid-returns-null-on-componen)
But this is not working for me.

this is my abc.js

```
clearSearch = () => {
        const { typeSearchBox } = this.props;
        this.setState({ searchPlaceholderValue: PROMPTRAISED });
        this.setState({ searchValue: '' });
        this.setState({ showClearIcon: false });
        const searchBox = document.getElementById(`SearchBox_${typeSearchBox}`);
        searchBox.focus();
    };
```

this is my abc.test.js

```
it('+++ inputs valid filtered search text', () => {
     categoryWrapper.find('ClearIcon').prop('onClick')();
});
```

on click of clearIcon clearseach is trigger.

Comment: Please add the code from the test file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mock `document.getElementById` function to return an object with `focus` function in your test file.

```
const mockUpObject = {
  focus: () => null,
};
global.document.getElementById = jest.fn(() => mockUpObject);
```

Comment: can we do the same for **blur**?
`searchBox.blur();`

Comment: Yes, we can. You can add blur function to mockUpObject